# What is the easiest way to use MDI icons in my Rails 4 Project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, material-design

I want to use [MDI](https://materialdesignicons.com/) icons in my new Ruby on Rails 4 project.

1. **How I integrate MDI icons with my Rails code?**
2. **What to include in my Gemfile?**
3. **What to include in my Application CSS?**

https://materialdesignicons.com/ offer only NPM way.

It should be SASS or CDN way. Or, another way what best you prefer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem "material_icons"
```

run

```
bundle install
```

and add

```
 *= require material_icons
```

to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

After this you can use Material Icons like this:

```
<%= content_tag(:i, "close", class: "material-icons") %>
```

More info: https://github.com/Angelmmiguel/material_icons

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to edit my css to include `*= require material_icons`. And, please edit your answer accordingly.